# Convert DB Join Query to Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following functions in my User model:

```
public function getInterests()
{

    return $this->hasMany('App\Interest')->get();

}

public function getGifts()
{

    return DB::table('gifts')
        ->join('sent_gifts', function ($join) {
            $join->on('gifts.id', '=', 'sent_gifts.gift_id')
                ->where('user_2', $this->id);
        })
        ->join('users', function ($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'sent_gifts.user_1');
        })
        ->get();

}
```

I couldn't understand how to create complex Eloquent Relationships, but I would like to use all of the benefits of Eloquent ORM, such as accessors and carbon instances on dates.

How would I go about converting my `getGifts()` function to an Eloquent Relationship?

P.S: I already have my **App\User**, **App\Gift** and **App\SentGift** models created.

Comment: According to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) your relationships are not properly formed. Try to establish them, according to these docs... Hints: 1. rename getInterests to interests and remove `->get()`. 2. rename getGifts to gifts and set up proper relationship...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this. It is my relationship.

**User Model**

```
class User extends Eloquent { 
   protected $table = 'users'; 
   public function posts() { 
     return $this->hasMany('App\Post'); 
   } 
}
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Eloquent { 
  protected $table = 'posts'; 
  public function comments() { 
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment'); 
  } 
 }
```

And query use like following..

```
User::with('posts.comments')->get();
```